# NSCell Custom Highlight

Tags: cocoa, nscell

I'm trying to subclass `NSCell` to draw a custom background highlight. The documentation seems to suggest that the overriding `highlight:withFrame:inView:` should allow me to do this but the method is never called.

Instead, I've overridden `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` which works fine - I can draw what I want in the cell. However, the issue is that I have to draw everything myself, losing the functionality of the type of NSCell I am extending - for example an NSTextFieldCell's ability to display text:

Custom drawn highlighted cell:

[image]

However, I just want to redraw the background (the highlight), and retain the ability to use the main functionality of the extended cell:

[image]

I could, of course, just draw the text myself too but I'm hoping there is an easier way of doing this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending `[super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];` (with whatever parameter names you’re using) after you’ve drawn your custom background?

Comment: @Bavarious - If I do that then the custom background is lost. Result is the same as the second screenshot as I'd presume that method draws its own background too.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Can’t you set a transparent highlight colour so that `super` won’t mess with your custom highlight, and then you use `-isHighlighted` inside `-drawInterior…` to decide how you should draw the background?

Comment: @Bavarious - Interesting idea. Returning [NSColor clearColor] for `highlightColorWithFrame:inView:` just showed through to the desktop like http://i.imgur.com/jy970.png. However, returning nil for the same method did what I wanted - http://i.imgur.com/joUom.png - thanks for your help!

Comment: Cheers! May I suggest you describe what you’ve done as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Bavarious I've managed to work it out. My extended NSTextFieldCell class implementation now contains:

```
-(NSColor *)highlightColorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    return nil;
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    if ([self isHighlighted]) {
        // Draw highlight background here
    }

    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

The key is to make sure you return `nil` for `highlightColorWithFrame:inView:` to stop `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` drawing a background and yet still calling it to draw the main content (in this case text).

Comment: How **exactly** you draw background ? I only can change the text color. I have used ...  ` if( [self isHighlighted] ) {
  
  NSColor *oldColor = [self backgroundColor];
  [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
  [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
  [self setBackgroundColor:oldColor];
  
 } ` but nothing happens! Thanks...

Comment: Have you actually overridden `-drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` rather than `-drawWithFrame:inView:`?

Comment: How do you do this with Swift? It's not possible to return nil from highlightColorWithFrame!!!!